# Changing "onmouseover" & "onmouseout" to a touchevent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently coding my first bigger website. It's a website for a photographer and one of the main html-pages is a navigation page with all the different project  each  leading to its corresponding photo album. I have done it so that each album has a cover-picture and when hovering over the album this cover changes to a specific drawing with each different album and changing back when removed. I have achieved this by using the html command "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" and then changing the src.
The problem that I am now facing is that onmouse events doesn't work on mobile devices and therefore i need some help with integrating a touch event listener.
Specifically do you think it's possible to make a simple js event listener that can use all my already existing onmouse events? Or how would you guys do it?
The whole thing is contained inside the parent container  and the three child elements or items inside <div class="column>.

I have tried to get into how event listeners work but i couldn't figure out how to link them directly to each specific album cover change in just one single function

[picture of html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbriD.png)

Comment: Take a look at [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) over on MDN.

Comment: Please add code as text within the question rather than as a picture of the code. That being said, you should probably start using `addEventListener` from your JavaScript rather than the `on...` attributes.

Comment: Most people using a touch screen just tap/click on stuff, it is not like they are dragging a cursor around which can enter or leave an area or element. So you will probably need to rethink this (or scrap the effect for touch users).

Comment: Please read this which will help you put the code into your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (though I also recommend you design for a touch device specially, as per @Karl-JohanSjögren comment).